# java: Calendar dont get correct date / time?

Tags: java, calendar

i use this code to convert a date-string into a unix timestamp:

```
int year = 2012;
int month = 2; // eg. for march
int day = 31;
int hrs = 0;
int min = 18;
```

this should represant this date/time 31.3.2012 00:18 or 3/31/2012 00:18 in english notation

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Berlin")); // GMT+1
cal.set(year, month, day, hrs, min);
unixtime = cal.getTimeInMillis() / 1000;
```

The result of unixtime is: `1333145929`
If i convert it back (`cal.setTimeInMillis(1333145929 * 1000);`) i got `30.3.2012 00:18`

I lost one day!

Comment: Can you try with another getTimeZone??? for example the opposite in the planet?

Comment: Can you post a complete example that shows the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**How are you printing out the `Calendar`?**

I think you are getting the GMT time, which is one hour behind and therefore one day behind at midnight.

Consider:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int year = 2012;
    int month = 2; // eg. for march
    int day = 31;
    int hrs = 0;
    int min = 18;
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Berlin")); // GMT+1
    cal.set(year, month, day, hrs, min);
    long time = cal.getTimeInMillis();
    System.out.println(time);
    cal.setTimeInMillis(time);
    final DateFormat sdf = SimpleDateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(SimpleDateFormat.FULL, SimpleDateFormat.FULL);
    System.out.println(sdf.format(cal.getTime()));
}
```

Output:

```
1333145915825
Friday, 30 March 2012 23:18:35 o'clock BST
```

Now if I add in a `TimeZone` to the `DateFormat`:

```
final DateFormat sdf = SimpleDateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(SimpleDateFormat.FULL, SimpleDateFormat.FULL);
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Berlin"));
System.out.println(sdf.format(cal.getTime()));
```

I get:

```
1333145887761
Saturday, 31 March 2012 00:18:07 o'clock CEST
```

So the `SimpleDateFormat` uses your default `TimeZone` when it formats and **not** the `TimeZone` of the `Calendar` (as you call `Calendar.getTime()`).

Comment: thanks it works but why in the first example i get 1333145915825
and in the second 1333145887761. The sdf.setTimeZone only applies to sdf.format and you print out the time directly?

Answer (score 0):

```
    int year = 2012;
    int month = 2; // eg. for march
    int day = 31;
    int hrs = 0;
    int min = 18;


    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Berlin")); // GMT+1
    cal.set(year, month, day, hrs, min);
    long unixtime = cal.getTimeInMillis();

    cal.setTimeInMillis(unixtime);

    //Lets print it!
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Berlin"));
    System.out.println(sdf.format(cal.getTime()));
```

For me code above prints : `03/31/2012 00:18:56`

How do you print your date?

Comment: @jlordo you didn't set time zone for SimpleDateFormat

Answer (score 0):

I've tried this code:

```
    int year = 2012;
    int month = 2; // eg. for march
    int day = 31;
    int hrs = 0;
    int min = 18;

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Berlin")); // GMT+1
    cal.set(year, month, day, hrs, min);
    long unixtime = cal.getTimeInMillis() / 1000;

    System.out.println(cal.getTime());

    System.out.println(unixtime);

    cal.setTimeInMillis(unixtime * 1000);

    System.out.println(cal.getTime());
```

And output is this:

```
Sat Mar 31 00:18:04 CEST 2012
1333145884
Sat Mar 31 00:18:04 CEST 2012
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is how you get 30.3.2012 00:18. The Calendar DATE field is OK, try this

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Berlin")); // GMT+1
    cal.set(year, month, day, hrs, min);
    long unixtime = cal.getTimeInMillis() / 1000;
    cal.setTimeInMillis(unixtime * 1000);
    System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.DATE));
```

output

```
31
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int year = 2012;
        int month = 2; // eg. for march
        int day = 31;
        int hrs = 0;
        int min = 18;

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone
                .getTimeZone("Europe/Berlin")); 
        cal.set(year, month, day, hrs, min);
        long unixtime = cal.getTimeInMillis() / 1000;
        cal.setTimeInMillis(unixtime * 1000);
        System.out.println(cal.getTime());
```

Output:

Sat Mar 31 03:48:10 IST 2012